# wpf user control - how to set text from outer uc

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem , i have 2 uc that displayed in main windows. 
i want when i press on button in the first uc the text in the other uc will change

this the axml i use and the code 
first uc

```
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Width="40" Height="40" Name="playbtn"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="playbtn_Click" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/img/player_play.png"  ></Image>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width="40" Height="40" Name="pausebtn" Grid.Column="1"   Grid.Row="0" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/img/player_pause.png" ></Image>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width="40" Height="40" Name="stopbtn" Grid.Column="2"   Grid.Row="0" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="/img/player_stop.png" ></Image>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>


  secound uc   <TextBlock Name="Progresstimertext" Text="00:00:00" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
```

so i want to press on start button and the timer will be change? how to

10x

Answer (score 0):

This should be managed in the View Model of your Main Window, as this seems the only location that has knowledge of *both* controls and it sounds as though each of your user control's shouldn't necessarily have knowledge of each other.

Ideally, you should have a reference to each of your user controls in the code-behind (or view model class is you have a dedicated one).

If in code behind, you would simply expose these by giving them names.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="your controls reference here">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </ColumnDefinition>
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:UserControl1 x:Name="Control1"/>

        <controls:UserControl2 x:Name="Control2" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Now you can reference them in your code behind by name **Control1** and **Control2**. These user control classes should be exposing the properties that you want to control, in your case **ProgressTimerText**, such that, in the code-behind, you can set it easily such as

```
Control2.ProgressTimerText = "00:00:00";
```

Where to do this? Well you probably want to create a **Stopped** event on your **Control1**, that you can attach to your code behind - in your case, something like **Stopped**. In your **UserControl1** class you should declare something like

```
public event EventHandler Stopped;
```

And then in the local event handler for the **Click** of the stop button, invoke that event.

```
private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Stopped != null)
        Stopped(this, e);
}
```

Attach that in your MainWindow:

```
<controls:UserControl1 x:Name="Control1" Stopped=Control1_Stopped/>
```

Now in your code-behind you should have something like:

```
private void Control1_Stopped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Control2.ProgressTimerText = "00:00:00";
}
```